# Paragraphs and pagebreaks in Multicols

Tags: paragraphs, multicol

I have the following problem. I am trying to make small paragraphs in a `multicol`. The thing I want to accomplish is that a paragraph does not get broken between two colones. I tried `minipage`s and `\begin{samepage}` without effect or either breaking the formatting entirely.

I am a LaTeX beginner so I lack the deeper understanding of functions and syntax. Can anyone help me with formatting and explain how/why it is working?

```
\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfile}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\subsubsection{Template headder}
\end{center}
some intro text some intro 
\begin{multicols}{2}

%This should stay as one block without pagebreaks

\paragraph{One headder} \hfill 1 point
\hrule
\vspace{3mm}
Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text 
test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test 
Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test  

%This should stay as one block without pagebreaks

\paragraph{Two headder} \hfill 2 points
\hrule
\vspace{3mm}
Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text 
test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test 
Text test Text test Text test Text test Text test  

\end{multicols}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```